# Emogrify HTML and CSS files (not emails)

Tags: php, html, css

I have been searching for information on how to use [Emogrifier](http://www.pelagodesign.com/sidecar/emogrifier/) to convert an HTML, with CSSv3 linked, into inline HTML formatting. So far, I keep finding things pertaining to sending emails to sites that don't allow CSS.

More information on my problem set: I have an HTML document, with linked CSS, that is nicely formatted and I need to open it as a doc(x). Word doesn't support CSS above v1. I am using v3. As of now, the formatting is horribly off when converting due to the lack of CSS. I have multiple HTML documents and CSS files to convert to inline and would like to not do it by hand.

I have attempted to use [Emogrifier](http://www.pelagodesign.com/sidecar/emogrifier/), but seem to always get an error page from my server `(using MAMP)`. The page works until it gets to the `Emogrify` portions. I have attempted the constructor with and without args. When without, I supplied the HTML and CSS with the set functions. I have also attempted to pass the files with both `fopen()` and `file_get_contents()`.

**Elements and Version:**

> - MAMP Version 2
> - Apache 2.0.64
> - PHP 5.4.10

**Question 1:** Can Emogrifier work on things other than emails?

**Question 2:** Is there another product/program that would better suite my needs?

**Question 3:** Is there something wrong with my code?

```
<?php
  include(emogrifier.php);

  $site = file_get_contents('file.html');
  $link = file_get_contents('file.css');

  $emog = new Emogrifier($site,$link);

  /* alternate call
  $emog = new Emogrifier;
  $emog->setHTML($site);
  $emog->setCSS($link);
  */
  $result = $emog->emogrify();

  print($result);

  ?>
```

**EDIT**

I have attempted to pass three types of variables to the constructor:

> - file path
> - file pointer (fopen())
> - string (file_get_contents())

When attempting to access the php page I get a Server Error in the browser:

> The website encountered an error while retrieving
>   http:// localhost/file.php. It may be down for maintenance or
>   configured incorrectly.

I have commented out the constructor and function call which allow the page to "work" with echo statements for testing purposes. Yet uncommenting even just the constructor causes an error.

When "running" the emogrifier.php file, the page loads just fine (white screen, no printouts).

This is all the information that I have for this problem.

**Final Edit**

I just wanted to wrap this one up.

I never got an emogrifier to work for my problem set. I ended up using Word Macros with heavy VisualBasic editing to get the formatting we wanted. This was a complicated solution as the Macro system is not well documented. Also, since I had a lot of tables and cell alterations to make, google searches were of little help since everything came up for Excel when searching for cell.

... and then they moved the report format to something else and my work wasn't use anyway! LOL

Answer (score 1):

> Can Emogrifier work on things other than emails?

Well, it actually works on HTML, not emails. The HTML is then intended to be used in Emails, but you can use it everywhere you like.

> Is there another product/program that would better suite my needs?

That is a good question! I tend to say: Yes, likely there is. Please contact a consultant that is specialized in finding the software components together with you.

> Is there something wrong with my code?

From the description you give I would say yes. Especially the part where you talk about an error. However as unspecific you describe that error, as unspecific I can only say: Yes, likely there is something wrong with your code.

Answer (score 0):

I have used Emogrifier successfully. Here is the code snippet that worked.

```
$emogrifier = new \Pelago\Emogrifier();
$emogrifier->setHtml($Data);
$cssFile = mb_substr($curFile, 0, 6) . 'override.css'; // each issue has a common CSS file
$emogrifier->setCss(fgc_UTF8($cssFile));
//After you have set the HTML and CSS, you can call the emogrify method to merge both:
$Data = $emogrifier->emogrify();
```